# So I accidentally said I was blind on my taxes... What should I do?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs

I thought it the blind checkbox was if your prescription was worse than -2.5 (mine is worse), but when looking around online for tax deductions, I found that the blind thing is only if your eyes are bad WITH your prescription on...  What should I do?

Comment: Your comment should be an answer @RonJohn

Comment: The earlier you disclose you made a mistake, and you want to pay all your dues plus interests and such, the better it will turn to your pocket and criminal record. If IRS/FBI catch you before you take initiative to speak, it will only go worse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If might have to fix this with your Federal and maybe even your state income taxes. On the Federal level you will need to file a 1040-X. Your state if the same fix is needed  should have a similar form.

You will have to go back as far as you can and fix each year. Generally you have three years to file the 1040-x when you are due a refund, but that limit goes away if you owe them more. Your state may have different rules. There will interest and penalties in addition to owing the additional tax.

There is another key factor. The blindness checkbox gives you a larger standard deduction. If you itemized that year then the incorrect statement might not change anything. The State rules may be different.

Just for reference, in [Publication 501 (2019), Dependents, Standard Deduction, and Filing Information](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p501#en_US_2019_publink1000221058)

> **Higher Standard Deduction for Blindness**
>
> If you are blind on the last day of the year and you don't itemize
> deductions, you are entitled to a higher standard deduction.
>
> **Not totally blind.**
>
> If you aren't totally blind, you must get a certified statement from
> an eye doctor (ophthalmologist or optometrist) stating that:
>
> - You can't see better than 20/200 in the better eye with glasses or contact lenses, or
> - Your field of vision is 20 degrees or less.
>
> If your eye condition isn't likely to improve beyond these limits, the
> statement should include this fact. Keep the statement in your
> records.
>
> If your vision can be corrected beyond these limits only by contact
> lenses that you can wear only briefly because of pain, infection, or
> ulcers, you can take the higher standard deduction for blindness if
> you otherwise qualify.

Comment: Would I still need to do this even if I didn't use the tax deductions? (I made less than $12,400)

Comment: This is my first tax filing, could I just correct it from now on?